# Python Sort Two Dimensional Dictionary By First Key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a 2D dictionary in python indexed by two IPs. I want to group the dictionary by the first key.

For example, the before would look like this:

```
myDict["182.12.17.50"]["175.12.13.14"] = 14
myDict["182.15.12.30"]["175.12.13.15"] = 10
myDict["182.12.17.50"]["185.23.15.69"] = 30
myDict["182.15.12.30"]["145.33.34.56"] = 230
```

so

```
for key1, key2 in myDict:
     print key1 +"   " +key2 +"   " +myDict[key1, key2]
```

would print

```
182.12.17.50   175.12.13.14   14
182.15.12.30   175.12.13.15   10
182.12.17.50   185.23.15.69   30
182.15.12.30   145.33.34.56   230
```

But I want to sort it so it would print

```
182.12.17.50   175.12.13.14   14
182.12.17.50   185.23.15.69   30
182.15.12.30   175.12.13.15   10
182.15.12.30   145.33.34.56   230
```

Any idea how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Can you give a real example of what you want for output?  The example you give for "after the sort" are assignment statements which you can put in any order you want.

Comment: @Daniel, the assignment statements were meant as an example of how it would print if you ran through it in a for loop, added more for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are a variety of options.  One of them would be to sort the keys before printing, something like this:

```
for key1 in sorted(myDict):
    for key2 in myDict[key1]:
        print key1 +"   " +key2 +"   " +myDict[key1][key2]
```

Another option would be to use the [sorteddict](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sorteddict.html) class from the [blist](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) module (disclaimer: I'm the author :) ), which will always return the keys in sorted order.

In either cases, since the keys are IP addresses, you might want to write a custom "key" function to pass to sort/sorted/sorteddict so they will sorted by their numeric value rather than lexicographically as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Dicts have no order, but what you can get is a sorted list of items.

```
>>> sorted((k, sorted(v.items())) for k,v in myDict.items())
[('182.12.17.50', [('175.12.13.14', 14), ('185.23.15.69', 30)]), 
 ('182.15.12.30', [('145.33.34.56', 230), ('175.12.13.15', 10)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom comparison function into Sorted.
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted

With it, you can specify which key to compare and how.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I have not understood the problem very well.

Wouldn't the output of above dictionary look like this:

```
>>> myDict
{'182.12.17.50': {'185.23.15.69': 30, '175.12.13.14': 14}, '182.15.12.30': {'175.12.13.15': 10, '145.33.34.56': 230}}
```

and then you could use OrderedDict to create a sorted dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are an unordered type and in your example I don't see a reason why you would want the dict to be ordered.

If you need to create an ordered series of the dictionary's contents, i.e. its items, you can do that simply by applying `sorted`:

```
# Returns sorted list of item tuples
sorted(myDict.iteritems())
```

Or check out `OrderedDict` if your Python version supports it and you know what it means to have a sorted dictionary.